# Traybar application shown on start

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've developed a WinForm application that run in background. The main form is hidden and to show the application I have to click the icon in the traybar.

(To develop this application I followed this post: http://windowsclient.net/articles/notifyiconapplications.aspx )

Now I'd like to modify my application so that the main form is shown when I start it, and that is hidden in traybar only when the form is minimized.

How can I call the `mainForm.Show()` method in my custom `ApplicationContext` when the application starts?

Comment: Have you tried: <pre><code>notifyIcon.Visible = false</code></pre>

Comment: I don't want to hide the `notifyIcon`, I'd like my application to start showing the main form and not just minimized in traybar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example source you linked to, so you will have to translate to your codebase, I added a call to ShowForm() in CalendarApplicationContext.InitializeContext().

This seemed to do what you wanted if i understood your request right.

```
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeContext() 
    {
        ....
        this.exitContextMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.exitContextMenuItem_Click);
        ShowForm();
    }
```